# Changing array elements

Tags: optimization, lisp, common-lisp

How do I optimize the next thing -- in my function I need a 2d array, where I then (dynamic programming) change some values, adding something to them. But when I try to optimize this, I get:

```
note: unable to
avoid runtime dispatch on array element type
 because:
Upgraded element type of array is not known at compile time.
```

I am using `(setf (aref table i j) value)`. I can guarantee that they will still be fixnum, as they were, and as I declared previously with `:element-type`.

Comment: you don't *declare* anything with `:element-type`. It just requests an array, which can hold elements of that type, probably using a space efficient representation - if available. It's like asking Lisp to allocate an array, possibly with some space optimization. But there is no further declaration of variables or objects going on. To declare types, you'd use DECLARE, THE, PROCLAIM, DECLAIM, ... and similar .

Comment: okay I added `(declare (type (simple-array (unsigned-byte 31) (* *)) table))`. Didn't help much. I can show whole code, but is it required..

Comment: you may find this interesting. In future please post your code and at least let us know what implementation you are using http://nklein.com/2009/06/optimizing-lisp-some-more/

Comment: If you have a question, make sure you have code included which demonstrates your problem in a reproducible way. Thanks.

Comment: The link in previous comment actually answers all my "how" questions. Not the why questions though. Not sure if I should post it as an answer.

Comment: You really, really need to post code.  Questions of the form 'here's this warning emitted by a compiler for my code, but no code, how do I make it better?' are not good questions: if I, for instance, wanted to reproduce the problem how do I do that without an example of it?

Comment: The code is too big itself, but i posted similar question here https://www.reddit.com/r/Common_Lisp/comments/a35cff/optimization_benchmark/

Comment: Why is this non-question not deleted? to moderators: please do so, the OP has not made any efforts to ask a meaningful question and when asked to post code, he did not.